# android databinding inside recyclerview

Tags: android, data-binding

I have checkboxes, edittexts and other inputs inside my recyclerview. I successfully implemented databinding whick means data is populated from the data I get from web service. When I change some input foe example change value 104 to 107 and scroll down (so that EditText) is now longer in viewport and scroll back I get value 104 again. It seems RecyclerView is caching old value and my that databinding library is not updating model.(Yes I'm using using Bindable attribute and other necessary stuff) and I also use executePendingBindings method inside adapter.

This is my RecyclerView adapter:

```
public class SimpleAttributesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleAttributesAdapter.AttributesViewHolder> {


private final Context context;
private final List<Attribut> allAttributes;

public SimpleAttributesAdapter(Context context,List<Attribut> _allAttributes)
{
    this.context=context;
    this.allAttributes=_allAttributes;
}


@Override
public AttributesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    RecyclerViewAttributesChildOneRowBinding binding= DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.recycler_view_attributes_child_one_row, parent, false);
    MyHandlers handlers = new MyHandlers();
    binding.setHandlers(handlers);
    return new AttributesViewHolder(binding);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AttributesViewHolder holder, int position) {
    RecyclerViewAttributesChildOneRowBinding binding=holder.getViewDataBinding();
    binding.setAttribute(allAttributes.get(position));
   holder.getViewDataBinding().executePendingBindings();

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return allAttributes.size();
}

public  class AttributesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

       private RecyclerViewAttributesChildOneRowBinding binding;

    public AttributesViewHolder(RecyclerViewAttributesChildOneRowBinding viewDataBinding)
    {
        super(viewDataBinding.getRoot());
        binding=viewDataBinding;
      binding.executePendingBindings();
    }
    public RecyclerViewAttributesChildOneRowBinding getViewDataBinding() {
        return binding;
    }
}
}
```

This is my layout file:

```
 < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <data>
    <import type="com.adriagate.adriagateonlineandroid.models.Attribut"/>
    <variable
       name="attribute"
      type="com.adriagate.adriagateonlineandroid.models.Attribut" />
   <import type="android.view.View"/>
   <variable name="handlers"            
       type="com.adriagate.adriagateonlineandroid.MyHandlers"/>

 </data>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@{attribute.Question}"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="@{attribute.Answer}"
    android:inputType="number"
    bind:visibility="@{attribute.isNumber ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
    />

<EditText
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="@{attribute.Answer}"
    android:inputType="text"
    bind:visibility="@{attribute.isString ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
    />
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    bind:adriagateentries="@{attribute.Choices}"
    bind:visibility="@{attribute.isSelect ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
    bind:selectedId="@{attribute.ChoiceId}"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
    />
 <CheckBox
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
bind:checked="@{attribute.Selected}"
bind:visibility="@{attribute.isBool ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"/>


  </LinearLayout>
  </layout>
```

This is my model:

```
public class Attribute extends BaseObservable {

@Bindable
public String getAnswer() {
    return Answer;
}

public void setAnswer(String answer) {
    Answer = answer;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.answer);
}



public List<Choice> getChoices() {
    return Choices;
}

public void setChoices(List<Choice> choices) {
    Choices = choices;
}



public int getType() {
    return Type;
}

public void setTypeype(int attributeType) {
    Type = attributeType;
}

@Bindable
public String getChoiceId() {
    return ChoiceId;
}

public void setChoiceId(String choiceId) {
    ChoiceId = choiceId;
   notifyPropertyChanged(BR.choiceId);
}

@Bindable
private String Answer; //tipovi 1


@Bindable
private String ChoiceId; //tipovi 1

private List<Choice> Choices; //za tip 3

private int Type;

public boolean isNumber() {
    return this.isNumber = this.getType()==1;
}
private boolean isNumber ;

public boolean isSelect() {
    return this.isSelect = this.getType()==3;
}
private boolean isSelect ;

public boolean isString() {
    return this.isString = this.getType()==2;
}
private boolean isString ;

private boolean isBool ;
public boolean isBool() {
    return this.isBool = this.getType()==5;
}

private boolean isChecked;
public boolean isChecked() {
    return this.Answer =="D";
}

}
```

Comment: Where's the code that takes the changes to the edit text and applies them to your data model?

Comment: User uses app, and changes value inside EditText, Two way databinding library updates the model. It should work that way. Two way databinding libraries in web world like angularjs work what way and this is how databinding should work.

Comment: 1) I don't see the code that takes the change in the edit text and persists it to the model. I don't see anything in the Android data binding page that describes any magic glue that's going to do that for you. 2) I don't see you calling the notifier when the data model changes.

Comment: 1) I'm relatively new to android but have some experince using web. In web world when user changes input , model is automatically updated, and when code updates model it is reflected in the UI. For example in the web world:  https://angularjs.org/  (Take a look at the input to the right of "The basics" section. So I should put all the listeners and manually update the model. I used to to this but what is the point of all that Observable things. 2) Inside the model I have call to  notifyPropertyChanged(BR.answer) because EdiText is bound to Answer attribute.

Comment: Because android does not support two way data binding and also does not good support to dynamically add elements in view( except in code!) I decided to quit from this approach. I will create views dynamically in code, and specify by design in code. How nice :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Android Studio 2.1, you can enable two-way data binding by using the "@={}" syntax in your layout.

For instance, try replacing :

```
@{attribute.Answer}
```

by :

```
@={attribute.Answer}
```

in your layout file.

For more reference, you can check this tutorial : https://halfthought.wordpress.com/2016/03/23/2-way-data-binding-on-android/